Bug with filtering when using "and"
today I encountered a filtering problem in a nested table query. The "and" operator cannot reference nested tables. To test this, I created a “testt” function and it returned the data I needed without a single error.
Below I will attach my original code, which also compares nested tables, but it also gives an error
//io.github.jan.supabase.exceptions.BadRequestRestException: "failed to parse logic tree ((recipes_and_dish.recipes.price.gte.15.0,recipes_and_dish.recipes.price.lte.16.0))" (line 1, column 22) (unexpected "r" expecting "not" or operator (eq, gt, ...))
suspend fun getDishWithFilter(fd: db_FilterData): List<db_Dish> {
    val columns = Columns.raw("""*, recipes_and_dish!inner(recipes!inner(price))""".trimIndent())
    val test = supabase.from("dish").select(columns = columns){
        filter {
            and {
                gte("recipes_and_dish.recipes.price", 15.0)
                lte("recipes_and_dish.recipes.price", 26.0)
            }
        }
    }

    Log.d("Supabase", test.data)

    return test.decodeList<db_Dish>()
}

//[some data]
suspend fun testt() {

    val test = supabase.from("recipes")
        .select(){
            filter {
                and {
                    gte("price", 15.0)
                    lte("price", 26.0)
                }
            }
        }

    Log.d("Test123", test.data)
}

//my original code
suspend fun getDishWithFilter(fd: db_FilterData): List<db_Dish> {
        val columns = Columns.raw("""*, recipes_and_dish!inner(recipes(price))""".trimIndent())
        val test = supabase.from("dish").select(columns = columns){
            filter {
                if (fd.categoryArr.isNotEmpty()) {
                    ////this part works
                    db_Dish::category_id isIn fd.categoryArr

                }
                if (fd.priceArr[0] != null) {
                    if (fd.priceArr[1] != null) {
                        //this part doesn't work
                        and {
                            gte("recipes_and_dish.recipes.price", fd.priceArr[0] as Double)
                            lte("recipes_and_dish.recipes.price", fd.priceArr[1] as Double)
                        }
                    } else {
                        //this part works
                        gte("recipes_and_dish.recipes.price", fd.priceArr[0] as Double)
                    }
                } else if (fd.priceArr[1] != null) {
                    //this part works
                    lte("recipes_and_dish.recipes.price", fd.priceArr[1] as Double)
                }
                //this part works
                fd.time?.let { time ->
                    lte("time", time)
                }
                //this part works
                fd.searchText?.let { searchText ->
                    if (searchText.trim() == "") {
                        db_Dish::name ilike "%${searchText.trim()}%"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        Log.d("Supabase", test.data)

        return test.decodeList<db_Dish>()
    }

What are the ways to solve this problem???
